# How do I use variables in a list? - flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, variables

im pretty new to flutter, tried for a while on my own now, but didnt find a solution online or within my own skills.
The problem:

`list<Widget>sport = [sport1(name: name1)];`

`name` is the variable I use in the child widget ( a callback if I remember right).

`name1`is the variable in the parent.

Now I want `name`  to be changed, when I change `name1`

The problem is, I cant use `name1` in list. I cant use any variable in list.

Error: `Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'name1'`

I dont have any other acces to my child widget `sport1` than in the list.

Code:

````
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Widget> sport = [sport1(name: name1),];
  String name1 = 'Max';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(child: sport[0]),),
        ),
      );
  }
}

class sport1 extends StatelessWidget {
  String name;
  sport1({Key key, this.name}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('$name does x pushups!'),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Hey Der Finn, could you add the code you are working on, it would help me (and others) to reach a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: list<Widget>sport = [sport1(name: name1)];  The closing bracket.

Comment: updated it as fast as possible :)

Comment: Why don't you initialize the sport list in a constructor? The issue is that `name1` cannot be referenced before its assigned

Comment: can you give me a code example of what you mean? I tried a few things and might misunderstood you.