# passing data to a widget that´s not parent/child - Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, widget

I´m new to flutter and need some help!
I know how to pass data from a parent to child, and the other way around.
But how do I pass data from a Widget that´s neither parent nor child from the receiving Widget?

Answer (score 0):

You pass it back to the parent, until you hit a parent that is ancestor of both and then you pass it down to the children, until you hit the child that it was meant for.

If that seems to be too much work, because they are too far apart in the tree, consider another approach to [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

Comment: I thought about this one too, but the only "connection" is found in a List. 
Unluckily passing data the classic way/ the way I know does not work in a List.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't, but have a look at the other means of state management and pick one that suits you.

Comment: If you got the time take a look at my previous question. Maybe you know what´s wrong 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332474/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-list-flutter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have multi option here :

1. use state Management (if you want just send parameters from a screen to another it's not recommend)
2. use something like this:

   ```
   class ClassName extends StatefulWidget {

       final int param1;

       const ClassName({Key key, this.param1}) : super(key: key);

   }
   ```

and when you want to route to this screen you can pass param1 like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(ClassName(param1: value));
```

3. List item
   you can use some lib like [autoRoute](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route)